# Why can we assign readonly IList collection with collection initializer?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

The `readonly` `Children` property of `StackLayout` is of type `IList<View>`. I got surprised knowing `Children` can be assigned with collection initializer as shown in the following code snippet (inspired by an example given by [Xamarin.Forms  documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options)):

```
public MainPage()
{   
    StackLayout sl = new StackLayout
    {
        Children =
        {
            new Label{Text="Start",HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start}
        }
    };
}
```

## Question

Why can it be assigned while it is a readonly property?

Next, I made a counter example as follows. Here the compiler complains that `Children` is a readonly property. It is understandable but the previous one is not. Could you tell me why?

```
public MainPage()
{                       
    IList<Label> labels = new List<Label>
    {
        new Label{Text="Start",HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start}
    };

    StackLayout sl = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = labels
    };
}
```

Comment: Auto properties with only `get` defined can be changed within constructor. On first case you're creating the object

Comment: The documentation of [readonly keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) may help you understand better.

Comment: @KevinKouketsu: Yes I know that "Auto properties with only get defined can be changed within constructor. ". But I am not defining a constructor here, so it is not relevant.

Comment: @WellHarassedProgrammer I was a little brief, i'm sorry about that. Like HimBromBeere said, you're not reassigning on first case. My bad!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A collection-initializer just **fills** the collection by calling its `Add`-method. It does not **create** it. Thus the following

```
Children = { ... }
```

is just syntactic sugar for this:

```
Children.Add(...);
Children.Add(...);    
Children.Add(...);
...
```

You see this assumes there already **is** a collection on which you can call `Add`, otherwise you´d get a `NullReferenceException.` So the code of the `StackLayou` is probably similar to this:

```
class StackLayout 
{
    public readonly WhataverCollectionType Children = new WhateverCollectionType();
}
```

As `WhateverCollectionType` implements `IEnumerable` and has an `Add`-method, you may use a collection-initializer.

Just an asside: Actually it´s bit different, the `StackLayout` derives from `Layout` which initializes the field to some `ElementCollection`, which implements `IEnumerable`.

Your second example clearly reassigns a list to `Children`, which is not allowed ony a `readonly`-field. You could also write this, which makes this a bit easier to understand:

```
StackLayout sl = new StackLayout
{
    Children = new List<Label> { ... }
};
```

This is compiled to something similar to this:

```
StackLayout sl = new StackLayout(); // will also assign Children to a new list
var list = new List<Label>();
list.Add(...);
list.Add(...);
...
sl.Children = list; // this re-assigns the member which is not allowed as it is readonly
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in first case you are constructing it(creating), not assigning.
In second case you are trying to modify it

Answer (score 0):

In the example from the documentation there is no new instance of `List<Label>` created and assigned to the `Children` property. The following code just calls the method `Add()` on the existing instance.

```
 Children =
 {
    new Label{Text="Start",HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start}
 }
```

basically it just calls

```
sl.Children.Add(new Label{Text="Start",HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start});
```

This on the other hand would also fail cause it would assign a new instance to the `Children` property:

```
 Children = new List<Label>
 {
    new Label{Text="Start",HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start}
 }
```